# Get sequence number behind data

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

My input file :

```
{empty line}
Test #1
data
{empty line}
Test #2
data
{empty line}
Test #3
{empty line}
Test #4
data
{empty line}
Test #5
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
4
```

How to get the sequence number (after the hashtag) if there is data available under each test using simple bash script?

Edit: The data under each Test contains few values, for example date, time, differences and so on. There are more than one data line between two Test. There is one blank line between each Test. The “Test” numbers will always be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers, starting at 1.

Comment: is this school work?

Comment: Will the data lines actually consist of the word `data`, or might they be “Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet” (i.e., anything other than `Test #`)?  Will there always be at most one data line between two `Test` lines, or can there be more?  Can there be blank lines in the data? What should happen if you have `Test #16` followed by one or more blank lines (but no *actual text*) and then `Test #17`?  Do you guarantee that the “Test” numbers will always be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers, starting at ``1``?

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: There are no blank lines between Tests. For example,Test #3/4 are next to each other. So you need to fix  that so responders don't misconstrue the problem.

Comment: @guest_7 sure thanks for the heads up.

Comment: In your earlier attempt at this question, which now appears to have been deleted, you provided us with your code. What happened to that here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```bsh
awk -F ' #' '
  function maybePrint() {
    if (NR > 1 && NR > lastLine + 1) {print lastSeq}
  }
  $1 == "Test" {
    maybePrint()
    lastSeq = $2
    lastLine = NR
  }
  END {
    maybePrint()
  }
' file
```

---

Changing the requirements is not nice, but because I like puzzles: If the file has blank lines:

```bsh
sed -n '
    /^Test #/ {
      s///
      =
      p
    }
    $=
  ' file \
| paste - - \
| awk -F '\t' '
    NR > 1 && $1 - prevLine > ($2 ? 2 : 0) {print prev} 
    {prevLine = $1; prev = $2}
  '
```

Comment: how do i avoid the blank line before each set of data?

Comment: do mind explaining the code?

Comment: I think it's pretty self-explanatory. Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: If i want to print the filename of Test when the data available, how do i include the code in this loop?

Comment: Use awk's builtin `FILENAME` variable

Comment: as i have few files, i have tried **awk ' {print FILENAME}' log_file_$j** but it just return output as log_file_1.txt, log_file_2.txt, log_file_3.txt and so on. May i know how to get the filename for each data generated from the code above?

Comment: In the maybePrint function, use `print FILENAME, lastSeq`

Comment: it works! why do i get empty line as the first [row](https://ibb.co/V9ZnHXR) ? Is it because  **if (NR > 1 && NR > lastLine + 1)**

Comment: Yes, the `NR > 1` part was supposed to suppress it, but the blank lines in the file (a new requirement) completely break this answer (the results now include `3`)

Comment: sorry for missing out that important information. I tried to print filename (**{print FILENAME, prev}**) with the new code you provided, i get output as **ਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭਭ**. May I know what causes this?

Comment: No idea. I suggest creating a new question so others will see it.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, you would typically choose between the `N;P;D` pattern and using the hold space:

**`N;P;D` approach**

You use that one to always have two consecutive lines in the buffer by appending a `N`ew line at the beginning, `P`rinting only the first line and starting the new cycle with `D`eleting the first line:

```
sed '$!N;/\ndata/!D;s/.*#//;P;D'
```

- `$!N` appends the next line if this wasn't already the last one
- `/\ndata/` matches a double line where the second line is `data`, the `!` inverts the match and `D` starts the next cycle with only the second line in buffer. Thus, if the second line doesn't start with `data`, continue with the next pair
- If we ever get here, we know the second line started with `data`, so `s/.*#//` will remove everything up to the `#`, `P` will print the first line (which is only the number by now), and `D` removes the first line for the next cycle (beware of two consecutive `data` lines! You don't tell what to do in this case.

**hold space approach**

Keep the line with the information to be printed in the `h`old space, but print it only on the trigger line:

```
sed '/data/!{h;d;};x;s/.*#//'
```

- `/data/!` addresses all lines that do not contain `data`. Place those lines in the `h`old space and `d`elete to start over without output
- If we are here, `data` did match,
  so `x`change buffers to get the saved line to the pattern space,
  remove the things up to `#` with `s/.*#//`
  and have the result printed by default output

Comment: This answer earns −¼ for assuming that the data is actually, literally the word ```data```. Lucky for you, I can’t cast a fractional vote.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no hashtag in the data:

```
sed -n 'N;/#.*#/D;s/.*#//;P' file
```

A more legible option:

```
sed -nE 'N;/(.*#)[0-9]+\n\1/D;s/.*#//;P' file
```

Pattern `(.*#)[0-9]+\n\1` tracks duplicate lines with hashtags.

Answer (score -2):

```
awk '{a[++i]=$0}/data/{for(x=NR-1;x<=NR;x++)print a[x]}' file| awk -F "#" '/Test/{print $2}'
```

output

```
1
2
4
```

Comment: −¼ for reading the entire file into memory (and holding it in memory) when all you need is one-line look-behind.  −¼ for potentially printing ``a[0]``, which isn’t initialized.  −¼ for assuming that the data is actually, literally the word `data`.  −¼ for piping `awk` into `awk`.  −¼ for potentially piping more data than is in the input file.  −¼ for not explaining.  Total score: −1½. Unfortunately, I can give you only −1.

Comment: Extra `-` points for introducing a variable `++i` to populate `a[]` instead of just `NR`, writing a loop from `NR-1` to `NR` instead of just `print a[NR-1] ORS a[NR]`, not testing that the `data` line is the first one after a `Test` line and so potentially printing many, sometimes duplicated, unwanted lines, and testing for `Test` anywhere in a line instead of just at the start followed by `<blank>#`.