# How to get filename if the data is available

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

My input files are `file_1.txt`, `file_2.txt`, `file_3.txt` and so on. These files contains data such as

```
$ head log_file_reset_*.txt
==> file_1.txt <==
Test #1
data

Test #2
data

Test #3

Test #4
data

==> file_2.txt <==
Test #1

Test #2
data

Test #3

Test #4
data


==> file_3.txt <==
Test #1
data

Test #2
data

Test #3

Test #4
```

The code I have right now to get the sequence number behind `Test` only if the data available under each `Test` from the input file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#################################################################################################
CWD=$(pwd)


  for j in {1..5} 
  
      do
sed -n '
    /^Test #/ {
      s///
      =
      p
    }
    $=
  ' file_$j.txt \
| paste - - \
| awk -F '\t' '
    NR > 1 && $1 - prevLine > ($2 ? 2 : 0) {print prev} 
    {prevLine = $1; prev = $2}
  ' >> 1_val.txt
```

The output i get from this code which is stored in `1_val.txt`:

```
1_val.txt
1
2
4
2
4
1
2
```

May i know how the code can be modified in order to get the filename (just the number) of the data listed in `1_val.txt` and store it in another file called `2_val.txt`?

The expected output:

```
2_val.txt
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never need sed when you're using awk. Here's how you should really be doing what that shell script in your question does (best I can tell), using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==1 {
    testId = ""
}
testId != "" {
    if (NF) {
        print testId
    }
    testId = ""
}
sub(/^Test #/,"") {
    testId = $0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file_*.txt
1
2
4
2
4
5
1
2
```

and then to print the above to 1 output file and the file number to another would just be this tweak:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==1 {
    testId = ""
    split(FILENAME,f,/[_.]/)
    fileId = f[2]
}
testId != "" {
    if (NF) {
        print testId > "1_val.txt"
        print fileId > "2_val.txt"
    }
    testId = ""
}
sub(/^Test #/,"") {
    testId = $0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file_*.txt
```

```
$ head *_val.txt
==> 1_val.txt <==
1
2
4
2
4
5
1
2

==> 2_val.txt <==
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
```

---

EDIT to address the comment below from the OP: here's how to use the above awk script inline in a shell script if you don't want it stored in a separate file:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    FNR==1 {
        testId = ""
        split(FILENAME,f,/[_.]/)
        fileId = f[2]
    }
    testId != "" {
        if (NF) {
            print testId > "1_val.txt"
            print fileId > "2_val.txt"
        }
        testId = ""
    }
    sub(/^Test #/,"") {
        testId = $0
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

and then you'd call the shell script as:

```
$ ./tst.sh file_*.txt
```

Comment: I am keep getting this error, line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `FILENAME,f,/[_.]/'
line 11: `    split(FILENAME,f,/[_.]/)'

Comment: Then you aren't executing the script in my answer and there's something wrong in some part of the script you're executing that you aren't showing us. You haven't said yet if the syntax error is coming from awk or your shell BUT the message says the issue is at `line 11` when my script has that code at line 3 so I suspect it's a quoting error in your shell script. Please [edit] your question to show the script you are trying to run and exactly the full error message you get when you try to run it. Copy/paste all of that from your terminal, don't try to re-type it.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to call awk to interpret an awk script from within a shell script (but you already do that in your question so this shouldn't be a surprise).

Comment: @Basil does it work for you now?

Comment: tst.awk script works fine but if i use the tst.sh, it says permission denied. For the tst.awk script, is there any possibilities to add **awk -f tst.awk file_*.txt** line inside the script itself?

Comment: Of course, you can call awk from a script just as easily as on the command line, but you don't need to -  you just haven't made `tst.sh` executable yet. Run `chmod oug+x tst.sh` and THEN execute it, just like you must have done for the shell script in your question.

Comment: There were mistakes in the filename. If my filename now is log_file_reset_*.txt, may i know how this can be solved? I try to edit this command split(FILENAME,f,/[_.]/) fileId = f[4]. But i get ਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱ਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼਴਴਴਴਴਴਴਴਴਴ਵਵਵਵਵਵਵਵਵਵ in 2_val.txt.

Comment: You're doing the right thing, those weird characters have nothing to do with my script. If you're getting weird characters in the output then it's because you have those weird characters in the input.

Comment: it is the same file but different name. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Awk doesn't invent characters to print them. Your file names are part of your input/output so when I say "if it's in the output then it's in the input" that includes the names of your files. [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680599/get-sequence-number-behind-data#comment1286576_680601) you had this problem with the answer you accepted to your previous question too - that is also a huge hint that this problem has nothing to do with the scripts we are posting. It seems like your file names have a bunch of weird characters in them.

Comment: the filename does not contain any weird characters as it just log_file_reset_1.txt

Comment: Again (last time) - awk does not invent characters to print. If there are weird characters in your output then there are weird characters in your input (or your OS is broken or something equally unlikely). Youre having the problem with my script, and you had the same problem previously with a totally unrelated script - the issue is not with the scripts. I'm sorry but you'll have to debug that yourself as we don't have access to your desktop with your real files and as you can see none of the answers you're getting have the problem you describe given the content you're posting in your question.

Comment: Okay noted. Just one last question... is there any way i can print the first line of the input file (which has the number from the filename, **----- Reset Loop 1 -------** of the data listed in 1_val.txt? I tried this **awk 'NR==1' file** but I am not so sure where i can insert this command in your script.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, please post a followup question as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum.

Comment: Noted and thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU sed with you , it can be done as like this:

```
sed -nsE '
  /#/N;/\n./F
  s/.*#([0-9]+)\n.+/\1/w1_val.txt
' file_?*.txt |
sed '/\n/P;y/_./\n\n/;D' ​> 2_val.txt

head [12]_val.txt
==> 1_val.txt <==
1
2
4
2
4
1
2

==> 2_val.txt <==
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Break up of lines:

- invoke sed wit no auto print (-n) option as we are not interested in printing pattern apace but just the file names.
- invoke sed with separate stream (-s) option. Normally sed treats all files as one stream.
- assuming data lines cannot contain the # character, we join the next line and check if it's non empty. In that scenario print current filename with F command.
- the second sed prints the string in between _ and dot.